# Fast API : How to return a str as JSON

Tags: python, fastapi

In python, using Fast API, I have a str that when print show (this is an example, the real str is more complex) :

```
[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]
```

I want to return this using Fast API as a JSON array.

**Using JSONResponse**

```py
def get_json(dataset: str, timeseries: str):

    test = "[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]"
    print(test)
    return JSONResponse(content=test)
```

The print is as expecting showing:

```
[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]
```

But the answer of the API when hitting the call is:

```
"[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]"
```

So my `str` is being serialised again and I don't know how to by-pass that.

**Using Response :**

The documentation of Fast API includes a page that describes how to return a Response directly (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/) where it is written:

> When you return a Response directly its data is not validated, converted (serialized), nor documented automatically.

But using this method leads to an error :

```py
def get_json(dataset: str, timeseries: str):

    test = "[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]"
    print(test)
    return Response(content=test, media_type="application/json")
```

```
> line 53, in get_json
    return Response(content=test, media_type="application/json")
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Response
description
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
content
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

By the way the exact xml example of the documentation gives the same error:

```
> line 61, in get_json
    return Response(content=data, media_type="application/xml")
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Response
description
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
content
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

I know I can convert my data to a an array or dict to be serialized I how want but as I already have the right str and don't want the job to be done several times.

Comment: What does your view decorator (`@app.get(..)`) look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I investigated as it was strange that the Fast API example didn't work.

The problem was that I was not using the right Response class.

So I had to import the right class to get things working as expected :

```
from fastapi import Response
```

The issue might be the same while trying with JSONResponse.

The following code is then answering the problem :

```
from fastapi import Response



def get_json(dataset: str, timeseries: str):

test = "[1592494390, 'test', -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, nan]"
print(test)
return Response(content=test, media_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per FastAPI's [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/):

> When you create a FastAPI path operation you can normally return any data from it: a `dict`, a `list`, a Pydantic model, a database model, etc.
>
> By default, FastAPI would automatically convert that return value to JSON using the `jsonable_encoder`

This means, when you return a string, it will be converted into a JSON string.

One way to verify this is by `curl`ing your endpoint and piping the result into `jq`.

Generally, you should leave the serialisation to FastAPI which is doing a great job at it.

On top of that, `nan` (not a number) is *not* part of the JSON standard

My suggestion is to make sure that the data that is supposed to be returned is a `list` or a `dict`, e.g.:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/get-json")
async def get_json():
    test = [
        1592494390,
       "test",
       -0.2761097089544078,
       -0.0852381808812182,
       -0.101153,
       None,
    ]
    return test
    # You could be explicit here and return a JSONResponse.
    # return JSONResponse(content=test)
```

Now, here's what this endpoint returns:

```
curl localhost:8080/get-json | jq type
"array"
```

If you run this command on your endpoint, it will probably show a `"string"` instead of `"array"`.

If your data is already serialised and you cannot get the original data directly, I would go with one of the suggested methods and deserialise it first.

However, in that case, you would have to escape all double quotes properly and replace the `nan` with something that JSON understands (e.g. `null`):

```py
import json
...
@app.get("/get-json")
async def get_json():
    test = "[1592494390, \"test\", -0.2761097089544078, -0.0852381808812182, -0.101153, null]"
#                        ^^    ^^                                                       ^^^^
#                    need to be escaped                                             cannot be nan

    return json.loads(test)
```

Now, this endpoint returns:

```
curl localhost:8080/get-json | jq type
"array"
```